# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'display' of undefined - how to fix it in my JS code of modal?

Tags: javascript

I tryed to make modal from [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp), but it doesn't work properly because of "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'display' of undefined". How to fix it?

```
var modal = document.getElementsByClassName("modal-inner");
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("open-button");
var close = document.getElementsByClassName("close-button")[0];


btn.onclick = function () {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

close.onclick = function () {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: try this: `close.style.display = "block";`

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Comment: `modal` is an array of HTML elements. You need to access a specific one or do a `forEach` over them to set their style.

Comment: getElementsByClassName returns an array. try like `modal[0].style`

Answer (score 0):

`modal` is an array of HTML elements and therefore has no property `style`.

You need to access a specific one with a given index or do a `forEach` over them to set the style of every item in that array:

## Specific one:

```
btn.onclick = function () {
    modal[0].style.display = "block";
}

close.onclick = function () {
    modal[0].style.display = "none";
}
```

## All modals:

```
btn.onclick = function () {
    modal.forEach(m => m.style.display = "block");
}

close.onclick = function () {
    modal.forEach(m => m.style.display = "none");
}
```

Comment: Oh, none of this solutions has helped :(

Comment: @unknown are you sure, that you are selecting the right elements? If your modals have the class `modal-inner`. Both solutions will 100% work..

Comment: Well, now it works, but has a new problem: it can close, but can't open when I click on open button. I used a Specific one

Comment: If my answer works, accept it and if you still have questions, that largely differentiate from the current one, open up a new question on StackOverflow. @unknown